# batchWriteItem of dynamodb doesn't insert more than 25 itens

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying insert more than 25 itens with dynamodb with this code:

```
    const writeBatch = async () => {
    const items = await accounts(26)

      for (let item of items) {
        const itemArray = createArray(item)
        const params = createParam(itemArray)
        dynamodb.batchWriteItem(params, (error, data) => {
            if(error) console.log(error) 
            else console.log(data)
        })
      }
    }

    writeBatch()
```

For this example, I tryng insert 26 itens, Each interaction for insert 25 itens or less. In the first insert 25, and in the second insert 1. But, when I search in dynambodb the last is not there.

It's the print of the each interaction of for loop:
[25 itens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj8bc.png)
[1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZEad.png)

Can you help me in this trouble

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of 25 items per request , as well as a limit of total item size in request of 16 MB.

see here for more limitations :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

if you need to send more than 25 items , you can split those into separate requests.

Comment: Yes, This is what I'm doing. In each interaction I do one request. The problem is that only one request is completed

Comment: how many writers do you have provisioned on your table ?
what is the item size that fails ?

Comment: The WCU is 5kb/s and each item contain 100 bytes. What's happen is that the first 25 insert is ok, but the next fails. There is no message error in console.log.

Comment: Is there any thing suspicions on the AWS metric dashboard?

Comment: I don't think no.

Comment: You might not be sending any thing in 26th item it might be empty ,  can you check if the 26 item that does not show up has any content.

Comment: In debug mode I check params value and it's there....